# Better ways of building Microservices in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, microservices

I'm into a very big project where we have already built some 50 to 70 Microservices in Nodejs. All these services imports some 5 to 10 core common modules. At this stage if there is any single line of change in common core module, we have to update,  build and deploy all the artifacts.  Is there any better way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the current architecture in more detail? Are you using docker? What's the current deploy & build process?

Comment: Yes, we do use dockers to build via Jenkins. We also have some docker-images with specific node_modules for the specific group of projects, so node_modules won't get downloaded every time we trigger a build until & unless there is a change in our package.json. When the build process is done, the artifacts get created with code & its node_module dependencies, so it is easy to move in higher (6 to 8) environments. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Sure, just wanted you to provide more information so that someone who can answer your question has all the needed information. Take my upvote for your question :)

Comment: Shouldn't common core modules be more stable overtime, and not require many changes over period of time. If these common modules are developed as services and as long as service interface doens't change, you are good to go, but otherwise if you are importing them directly, you will have to go through the process until the module gets matured.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @skjagini core modules should be stable, they should truely be core. In general I advocate for sharing as little as possible between your microservices, they should be independently developed and deployable. They should not require deployment synchronisation where you need to co-ordinate deployments of all your microservices least you break something. If that is the issue you are finding you have yourself a distributed monolith not a microservice architecture.

I cant see any easy resolution to the issue you post. If common code does change then naturally any deployable unit that uses that common code needs to be rebuilt and redeployed. The only exception to this would be if the change is not required by a particular deployable, and in this case it probably means your modules are doing too much and don't have a clear purpose or are too large.